# Django, automatic HTML "sanitizing" when putting HTML to template, how to stop it?

Tags: python, html, django, templates, html-sanitizing

I'm kind of confused by this because it seems that Django templates have optional HTML filters but this seems to be happening automatically.. I am making this demo app where the user will do an action that calls a python script which retrieves a url, I then want to display this in a new window.. its all fine except when the display comes back, the HTML is sanitized in this format (I see this when I view the page source, in the browser it shows as regular HTML:

```
&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd&quot;&gt;&lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot; xml:lang=&quot;en&quot; xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta content=&quot;text/html; charset=utf-8&quot; http-equiv=&quot;content-type&quot; /&gt;&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;//&lt;![CDATA[
si_ST=new Date
```

this is the regular HTML version of the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" /><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ si_ST=new Date //]]></script><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ _G={ST:(si_ST?si_ST:new Date),Mkt:"en-
```

I'm just outputting this to a basic block in my html template, the template has no other formatting (no HTML, etc), just 1 block where this output goes.. any advice on why this is happening and how to display the regular HTML (so it would show the page in the browser and not the HTML text) is appreciated.. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the safe filter:

```
{{ myvariable|safe }}
```

If you need large parts of your template treated like this (that is, if you find yourself using `|safe` over and over), you can disable the autoescaping whole-sale:

```
{% autoescape off %}
blah {{myvariable}} blah {{myothervariable}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: I've got this: {{content |safe}}

but then I get an error: "TemplateSyntaxError at /web_auto/call_mechanize_script/

Could not parse some characters: content| ||safe"

Comment: the {% autoescape off %} works fine.. thanks for that, so I am giving you the correct answer, not sure why it won't work for the other way

Comment: it should be {{ content|safe }}, without a space between "content", "|", and "safe.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the "safe" filter, which disables Django's default escaping:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Comment: Can anyone help with the syntax, i see where it says about safe, but I can't figure out the syntax, I am trying {{ myvariable safe}} and some other things but its not working

Comment: I did try that but get an error, I mentioned in Ned Batchelder's answer

Answer (score 2):

There is also [autoescape](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#autoescape) which controls escaping block wide.